# Display Portal Site Collection within master page

Tags: master-page

I have a couple of nested site collections e.g.:

- http://intranet (Site Collection Name: Intranet, Portal Site Collection)
- http://intranet/sites/sales
- http://intranet/sites/marketing

Is there a SharePoint/ASP.NET control that could display the name and URL of the Portal Site Collection (Intranet). I am not looking for a code solution but for a control that I could embedded intro master page as part of breadcrumbs trail e.g. `Intranet > Sales > Telesales`

Answer (score 2):

For a no code solution, you could try building a custom sitemap

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-1-Implementing_Consistent_Navigation_across_Site_Collections.aspx

```
<siteMap>
  <siteMapNode title="Intranet" url="http://intranet">
    <siteMapNode title="Sales" url="http://intranet/sites/sales">
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode title="Marketing" url="http://intranet/sites/marketing">
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Then set the SiteMapProviders for your breadcrumb control.

```
<asp:SiteMapPath
    runat="server"
    SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
    RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
    NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode"
    CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
    RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
    HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
    SkipLinkText=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried configuring the Portal Site Connection in the Site Collection Administrators setting for each site to point to the "Intranet" site? I'm a little rusty on this, but I think that in SharePoint 2007 that would set the breadcrumbs up to work properly with the Portal as the top-level site for the navigation.

Based on what I'm seeing here, I would expect that to work the same way: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263357.aspx.

John

Comment: Sure I did that, but it does not show. Maybe I am using wrong breadcrumbs control, but tried a couple of them and it seems neither will show it.

Comment: You need to change few lines in master page in order to get it work in SHarePoint 2013. 
Looking for <div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox"> remove the "style="display:none" and another "Visible= 'false'" in below.